# array sorting based on 3 variables

Tags: javascript

I have an array with 3 types of values in which I wish to sort them.

If I only use one variable it goes all pretty well, but it all goes wrong when i want to use 3 types of variables to determine sorting order.

**First variable condition:** if obj.sortorder == 999999 send it to the end of the line(there is only one of this one);

**if not true then**

**if (date < other date)** put it in front of the one before

**if(date > other date)** put it behind the other one

**if dates are equal** look to sortorder to determine the order in which to apppear.

**Then** loop over array, reset all sortorder variables to be properly ascending in the new order.

**Then** splice in a new value(15th), but then it doesn't appear next to the other one, even though they have duplicate values.

My head hurts from trying to figure this one out, I just can't seem to get them in the right order.

Basically the way they are created here they should come out in the first sort. But yet the first sort is messed up with values all over the place except where I want them.

The second sort puts them miraculously in the right order but puts the 16 between the two fifteens whilst the fifteens should be next to eachother. and somehow the 24th ends up as the 9999 after the reassignment whilst the 29th should have remained as the last one.

Who can help me with this?

If you press run code snippet you get the garbled output I currently get.
The first set is what all the others should look like, except for the last one where the 15's should be hugging eachother.f

```js
elements = [];
for (var c = 0; c < 30; c++) {
    elements[c] = {
        sortorder: c,
        getDate: function () {
            return new Date(2015, 06, this.sortorder)
        }
    };
}

function log(what) {
    var elem = document.getElementById('sortorder');
    elem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(what + "\n"));
}
for (c = 1; c < elements.length; c++) {
    log(c + " = " + elements[c].getDate() + " - " + elements[c].sortorder)
}
log('--------------------------------');
elements[elements.length - 1].sortorder = 9999999;

this.elements.sort(function (one, two) {
    /**
     * Failsafe to prevent the last element to be placed in the middle
     */
    if (one.sortorder >= 9999998) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (two.sortorder >= 9999998) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (one.getDate() < two.getDate()) {
      return -1
    } 
    if (two.getDate() > one.getDate()) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (one.sortorder < two.sortorder) {
       return -1;
    }
    if (one.sortOrder > two.sortorder) {
       return 1;
    }
    return 0;
             
});

function log(what) {
    var elem = document.getElementById('sortorder');
    elem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(what + "\n"));
}
for (c = 1; c < elements.length; c++) {
    log(c + " = " + elements[c].getDate() + " - " + elements[c].sortorder)
}
log('--------------------------------------------------------------');
elements.splice(17, 0, {
    sortorder: 15,
    getDate: function () {
        return new Date(2015, 06, 15)
    }
});
for (var c = 1; c < this.elements.length; c++) {
    if (c < this.elements.length - 1) {
        this.elements[c].sortorder = c;
    } else {
        this.elements[c].sortorder = 9999999;
    }
}
for (c = 1; c < elements.length; c++) {
    log(c + " = " + elements[c].getDate() + " - " + elements[c].sortorder)
}
```

```html
<pre id="sortorder">
</pre>
```

Comment: code might be more readable with `else if`

Comment: I made it in this order to be easier to trace for myself where goes what. and this does the same. if I use else if it becomes harder for me to trace where goes what after an if and which else belongs to what if.

Comment: What do you mean by **but then it doesn't appear next to the other one, even though they have duplicate values.** ?

Comment: Your code would read a whole lot better if the sort-compare function simply contained a series of `if ... then return ...` statements, instead of one big fat nested-if with a single `return` statement at the bottom . . .

Comment: @RemyGrandin if you press run code snippet and look at the third output you see that the 15th is followed by the 16th and then the next 15th. it should be 15th, 15th, 16th

Comment: @MikeRobinson or using returns or assigning the value to a single return variable that I can log at the end without having duplicate logging entries everwhere.  Thats the reason why it looks like it looks.

Comment: *Ahhh....* I see.  :-)

Comment: I modified it though. is it now more readable?

Comment: `The second sort puts them miraculously in the right order`: You don't perform a second sort after your `splice`, you just renumber the `sortorder`.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you mean by "Then splice in a new value(15th), but then it doesn't appear next to the other one, even though they have duplicate values."

This does everything but that.

```js
      var last;
var newArray = [];
for(var obj in array){
  obj = array[obj];
  if(obj.sortorder === 999999)
    last = obj;
  else {
    for(var item in newArray){
      if(obj.date.getTime() < newArray[item].date.getTime()){
        newArray.splice(item, 0, obj);
        break;
      }
      if(obj.date.getTime() === newArray[item].date.getTime()){
        if(obj.sortorder > newArray[item].sortorder){
          newArray.splice(item, 0, obj);
          break;
      }
        else{
          newArray.splice(item + 1, 0, obj);
          break;
      }
      }
    }
  }
}
newArray.push(last);
var sortorder = 1;
for(var item in newArray){
  if(newArray[item].date.getTime() > newArray[item - 1].date.getTime())
  newArray[item].sortorder = ++sortorder;
}
```

Comment: this won't comple. unexpected token break; Please note that it has to be browser compatible. And i can't put my script in strict mode. dupicate dates should follow eachother up. 1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,7,8,8,8,8,9,10,11,11,12,12. When dates are duplicates its up to sort order to determine the order.

Comment: Oops. I was lazy with my break statements. I fixed the problems you pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimenting, fiddling, swearing, googling, the normal process in a situation like this I finally got the solution.
I guess I was overthinking things once again.

Thanks for helping out and thinking along.

```
  elements.sort(function(one,two) 
        {
        var ret = 0;
        /**
         * Failsafe to prevent the last element to be placed in the middle
         */
        if(one.sortorder >= 9999998) {

            ret = 1;
        }
        else {
            if(two.sortorder >= 9999998) {

                ret = -1;
            }
            else {
                if(one.getDate() - two.getDate() !== 0) {
                    ret = one.getDate() - two.getDate();
                }
                else {
                    ret = one.sortorder - two.sortorder;                        
                    }

            }
        }
        console.log(ret);
        return ret;
        });
```